# Why this error occurs while trying to run java in vs code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I'm trying to use vs code for java. but get this error while running the code I tried to find the solution but I couldn't find, If any solution available please refer: [image: error]

Comment: if the error is while "running the code", it's quite obviously not a compiler-error. You don't show any code, nor do you show an error

Comment: Hi Zinan, you didn't actually include the error you're getting. We'll need that!

Comment: I updated the question, please recheck!

Comment: It looks like the Java tools are not installed or not in your `PATH`.

Comment: instead of trying to run code,. try typing: java -version in powershell.  You'll get the same error until you download and install java and it's in your PATH.   Once you get java to print the version, you'll be able to move to code.

Comment: Please don't provide either of these: terminal commands, code, error messages as images. Always include them as a **text** formatted appropriately.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Add the jdk path to your windows system environment.

Then in your VS code workspace settings add the path too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).